geopandas testing AttributeError
Has anybody worked with geopandas testing module?
I'm getting AttributeError: module 'geopandas' has no attribute 'testing'
with following code:
geopandas.testing.assert_geodataframe_equal(df1, df2)

I also tried print(dir(geopandas) but I can't seem to find testing module that way either.

You need to explicitly import the testing module with import geopandas.testing... otherwise it won't be found.
Sample script:
import shapely
import geopandas
import geopandas.testing

poly1 = shapely.Polygon([(0, 0), (0, 10), (10, 10), (5, 0), (0, 0)])
poly2 = shapely.Polygon([(5, 0), (8, 7), (10, 7), (10, 0), (5, 0)])

intersection_nogridsize = poly1.intersection(poly2)
gdf1 = geopandas.GeoDataFrame(geometry=[poly1, poly2])
gdf2 = geopandas.GeoDataFrame(geometry=[poly2, poly1])

geopandas.testing.assert_geodataframe_equal(gdf1, gdf2)


Perfect this worked! Didn't know that it would require explicitly import geopandas.testing to work. Thanks a lot! Really appreciate your response.
